# binding not being done with json data

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, binding

I have a listbox and its datacontext is set to a collection. In the background I am fetching data and giving it to the binding element. But it is not reflected in my design. Code goes as follows.

```
<ListBox Name="StatusListBox"
                 DataContext="{Binding StatusCollection}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In the Page definitions I gave as

```
DataContext="{Binding StatusViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignData Source=/Data/SampleData.json, Type=data:DataSource}}"
```

In cs file I have a statusviewmodel and i give the statusviewmodel, the content i fetched.

```
public ObservableDictionary StatusViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusViewModel;
        }
    }

    private async void GetStatusOnline()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        ObservableCollection<string> statusCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string textcontent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(textcontent);
            DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
            this.StatusViewModel["StatusCollection"] = dataSource.GetStatusCollection(textcontent);
        }
    }
private ObservableCollection<Status> _statusCollection = new ObservableCollection<Status>();
    public ObservableCollection<Status> StatusCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this._statusCollection;
        }
    }
public IEnumerable<Status> GetStatusCollection(string textcontent)
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(textcontent);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["items"].GetArray();
        foreach (JsonValue value in jsonArray)
        {
            StatusCollection.Add(new Status(value.GetString()));
        }

        return StatusCollection;
    }
```

The sample json data is

```
{
"items": [
    "Hi\n",
    "This is my new status. How is this?\n",
    "This is thrid line."
]
}
```

Comment: You have set the *DataContext* of your page to ViewModel, but your method *GetStatusCollection* operates on variable which is not in *DataContext*, therefore it probably won't have effect on UI. Is it possible that you can share a working sample with the problem?

Comment: @Romasz On navigation I set the StatusViewModel to have a key and the value to be the observable collection. And that collection has status objects. What is not in DataContext? I can share the code. but that is pretty much what I have here.

Comment: Have you tried <ListBox Name="StatusListBox" DataContext="{Binding StatusCollection}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">? So you are setting this in navigation method. It will be much easier for me to look at it if I had a working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not settings the `ItemSource` property of the `ListBox`. Change

```
DataContext="{Binding StatusCollection}"
```

to

```
ItemSource="{Binding StatusCollection}"
```

Comment: I have added both but there is no result in listbox. I was actually get inspired from ILoveCupCakes app from bob tabor tuts in channel 9.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I'll take a swing at this.
Looking at your XAML code for the Listbox.ItemTemplate and the DataContext,
you've set the data context to be Binding StatusCollection, and in your page definitions you have the DataContext as the Binding StatusViewModel. As well as d:DataContext is {Binding Source={d:DesignData Source=/Data/SampleData.json, Type=data:DataSource}

The issue lies in the Listbox's ItemTemplate for the TextBlock. Since you have the text set as {Binding} which is shorthand, it is assuming that the DataContext is for StatusCollection. In reality, the datacontext you want is for the DesignData source for the JSON file.

So I would suggest changing your StatusViewModel to reflect calling the JSON file, otherwise you have disjointed code whereas your JSON file is never actually read.

Comment: design data is ignorable. there is wrong the item source of the listbox only. i shouldnt give both data context and item source at once to list box.